# Drop Down Menu Help for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

Please help me out with this issue: I'm using Meembo template for my joomla 2.5.14. and I created drop down menu from the top menu. The problem now is that when you hover your mouse on the parent menu, the sub menu will not drop down but if you click on the parent menu first and the parent menu page loads, the sub menu will drop down on mouse hover and display all the sub-menu.
please, help me solve this problem. I will like the sub menu to be displayed once there is a mouse over on the parent menu.
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the template?

Comment: Please post some code or a link to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a javascript conflict to me.. check if some module published on front page is causing this (you can check simply by unpublishing module and refreshing the homepage) ... alternately you could try to install some drop down menu from joomla extension directory 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus

you would need to style it to fit your template of course ...